# JavaScript regex split on word or colon

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I'm trying to get a JavaScript regular expression to work for splitting on the word `as` or a colon. Here are the following test cases:

```
// Should all return ['test', 'test1']
test as test1
test: test1
test : test1
test :test1
test:test1
```

It should also work and preserve whitespace and newlines. Here is what I have so far working with `as`:

```
sentence.split(/\bas\b/);
```

I tried getting this to work with:

```
//yields: ['test', undefined, 'test1']
sentence.split(/(\bas\b)|\:/);
```

Can somehow help get this working with both `as` and `:`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
s.split(/\s*(?:\bas\b|:)\s*/)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JCUoji/1)

**Details**:

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:\bas\b|:)` - either a whole word `as` or `:`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.

Tests/examples:

```js
var ss = ['test as test1', 'test: test1', 'test : test1', 'test :test1', 'test:test1'];
for (var s of ss) {
  console.log(s.split(/\s*(?:\bas\b|:)\s*/));
}
```